# PDO query with quotes

Tags: php, pdo, quote

I developping an admin panel, i have the PDO stuff for my db. Here is my post PHP for update texte in my website:

```
$text1= $_POST['text1'];
$text2= $_POST['text2'];
$query = $con->prepare("UPDATE `home` SET text1='$text1', text2='$text2' WHERE id=1;");
$query->execute();
if ($query) {
    echo 'good';....}
```

If i write quotes it's say my sql query is not good. I have tried quote() and prepare() but don't work too. How can i do for use quote in my input ?

PS: In all my query i have specials char like: é à ü ù and other (i'm french)

Comment: Please read http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php-database-access-are-you-doing-it-correctly--net-25338 and use **proper** prepared statements, that will fix your problem

Comment: `$text1= $_POST['text1'];
$text2= $_POST['text2'];
$query = $con->prepare("UPDATE 'home' SET text1= :1 text2=:2 WHERE id=1;");
$query->bindParam(':1', $text1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':2', $text2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();`

Comment: @SergeyBelyakov It's the same as Steve reply ?

Comment: @Flavien317 it's seems like as Steve's reply?

Comment: @SergeyBelyakov almost, just :1 replace ?. But i don't know wich is the best

Comment: @Flavien317 It's a different approaches. I like to use the named parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use bound parameters:

```
$text1= $_POST['text1'];
$text2= $_POST['text2'];
$query = $con->prepare("UPDATE `home` SET text1=?, text2=? WHERE id=1;");
$query->execute([$text1, $text2]);
```

Comment: thanks, it's work, but there are other way because i like to have my $variable in my query ?

Comment: Huh? Please explain what you mean?

Comment: I just wan't to know which is the best method for have all special char in my query

Comment: Ok, so could you explain whats not working with the above? How is it failing? What chars are getting removed? And how did you test that they are removed (and not just escaped)

Comment: All working good, thanks, I will just wanted what is the best way for have special char in input and query.